# What are the possible ways to ARCHIVE the attachments in Salesforce?

Tags: opportunity, attachment

Scenario : Some attachments specific to an opportunity are available under Notes and Attachments of the the Opportunity . Out of those set of attachments,some are obsolete and hence would like to Archive them. Reason : The user should be able to consult obsolete attachments may be at a later point of time.

I am looking for the possibilities to achieve this. Any pointer/suggestions will be a great help.

Thanks,
Shruti

Answer (score 1):

You can use Amazon S3 cloud storage and migrate archived attachment to S3.

There is already toolkit available for this with sample code.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Amazon_Toolkit

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Force_for_Amazon_Web_Services

If you compare the cost S3 storage is much more cheaper than SFDC

AFAIK:

SFDC File Storage was $5 / mo for 1 GB
S3 File storage was $0.0300 for 1 GB